# PHP: Using browscap.ini on shared host. - ini_set() failing

Tags: php, shared-hosting, browscap

I'm trying to use get_browser() , unfortunately my page is on a shared host, and I have no access to php.ini.

I have downloaded the latest version of browscap.ini and placed in my document root. I have then added the following:-

> if (!ini_set('browscap', '/home/*private stuff*/browscap.ini')) {
>   echo "Failed to set browscap";
>   } else {
>   echo "browscap = [" . ini_get('browscap') . "]";
>   }
>   exit();

But this fails, (nb: the echo statement for the failed condition always shows [] - even if I didn;t have the browscap.ini file the setting should still show up in the ini_get.... shouldn't it?)

I have looked at the previous questions on this and they don't seem to help,  any ideas?

Answer (score 12):

I hadn't heard of this feature before, but in [Googling around](http://www.google.com/search?q=browscap.ini&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a) I came across [phpbrowscap](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap) (previously at a [this Google Code repo](http://code.google.com/p/phpbrowscap/)( which is a standalone class that you should be able to use in your hosted environment.  The author supports many configuration files and [the QuickStart](https://github.com/GaretJax/phpbrowscap/wiki/QuickStart) (previously [here](http://code.google.com/p/phpbrowscap/wiki/QuickStart)) looks especially easy.

Comment: Thanks Tony,

I've followed your suggestion and now have phpbrowscap working - so that's great.

Unfortunately it means that I will never learn why the ini_set() approach didn't work, but I guess life's too short....

thx jon

Comment: Just wanted to add my voice saying this worked like a charm! Great browser detection! (I initially wanted to use http://deviceatlas.com but its a memory hog and likely won't work on many of our client shared hosts)

Answer (score 11):

As per the [PHP manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.list.php), 'browscap' is changeable only in the system php.ini and/or httpd.conf. You cannot set it at the script level.

Comment: Do you mean by `httpd.conf` the .htaccess file?