# How to get user agent in PHP

Tags: php, user-agent

I'm using this JS code to know what browser is user using for.

```
<script>
  document.write(navigator.appName);
</script>
```

And I want to get this navigator.appName to php code to use it like this:

```
if ($appName == "Internet Explorer") {
  // blabla
}
```

How can I do it?

Comment: Related: [reliable user browser detection with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php).

Answer (score 286, accepted):

Use the native PHP `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable instead.

Comment: Pay attention, this can be not set!

Comment: In PHP7+, you can write `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']??null` to have it return null instead of throw an error when it isn't defined

Comment: Or do this, if you just want to do string manipulations later and do not want to care about null or not set:
$ua = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'].'';

Comment: Or simply check with `isset()`... Clean and readable code should always be a high priority.

Comment: @StanE - The PHP 7 version is perfectly fine. Novel !== Unreadable.

Comment: Of course, this variable should be considered unsafe. Don't trust the input it provides (filter/sanitize it)

Answer (score 8):

I use:

```
<?php
$agent = $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];

if( preg_match('/MSIE (\d+\.\d+);/', $agent) ) {
  echo "You're using Internet Explorer";
} else if (preg_match('/Chrome[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/', $agent) ) {
  echo "You're using Chrome";
} else if (preg_match('/Edge\/\d+/', $agent) ) {
  echo "You're using Edge";
} else if ( preg_match('/Firefox[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/', $agent) ) {
  echo "You're using Firefox";
} else if ( preg_match('/OPR[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/', $agent) ) {
  echo "You're using Opera";
} else if (preg_match('/Safari[\/\s](\d+\.\d+)/', $agent) ) {
  echo "You're using Safari";
}
```

Comment: Similar answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/59897333/3733214

Answer (score 6):

You can use the jQuery ajax method [link](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) if you want to pass data from client to server.
In this case you can use `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` variable to found browser user agent.

Comment: is this working `$_SERVER['USER_AGENT']`??  Should be `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`???

Answer (score 6):

You could also use the php native funcion [get_browser()](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

IMPORTANT NOTE:
You should have a browscap.ini file.

Comment: This requires you to have an up-to-date browscap.ini file

Comment: it does and there are quite a few online resources where you can download one for your site, such as [browscap.org](https://browscap.org/)

Comment: return null or false

Comment: make sure you have a browscap.ini file

Answer (score 2):

PHP 8 have this features `$_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA']` [Sec-CH-UA](https://wicg.github.io/ua-client-hints/#sec-ch-ua)  let's you detect the browser name directly

```
if (  strpos ( $_SERVER['HTTP_SEC_CH_UA'],'Opera'   ){
       //        
    }
```