# How to get specific device information from browser

Tags: php, browser, device

I want the laptop, notebook and other device name and model that user is browsing from. 
So if a user is browsing my website from device, 'Dell inspiron' then I need this. How to get this?

Comment: User agent is what you should look for

Comment: [Check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10243841/how-to-get-user-agent-in-php)

Comment: try $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']

Comment: This does not return the model name of my laptop. I need the laptop model and device info.

Answer (score 0):

Should be useful for you, visit here
https://detectdevice.com/

Comment: Thanks I seen that but I need it for laptop device too. It works only for mobile.