# PHP if is chrome on windows

Tags: php, windows, google-chrome, user-agent, browser-detection

I'm doing some PHP includes depending on browser, and need to target Chrome on Windows

I've got this to target all IE browsers (MSIE) is there some way I can also target Chrome for Windows?

```
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) && 
(strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'MSIE') !== false))
    return true;
```

Comment: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/useragentstring.php

Comment: in javascript  you can detect chrome with Gecko

Comment: UA sniffing is so unreliable as to be basically pointless. If you feel you must do it anyway, [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) is the "right" way to do it.

Comment: DaveRandom, why is it so unreliable? I'm just learning about it...

Comment: possible duplicate of [reliable user browser detection with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php)

Answer (score 3):

If possible, your best bet would be to configure [browsecap](http://www.php.net/manual/en/misc.configuration.php#ini.browscap) in `php.ini` and use the [`get_browser()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php) function to determine the user agent and platform.

I just checked Chrome's user agent on a Windows PC and you can probably match against this:

```
function isChrome($user_agent) {
    return stripos($user_agent, 'chrome') !== false &&
           stripos($user_agent, 'win') !== false);
}
```

Comment: The user agent you want to check, probably `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` if its set.

Answer (score 1):

Try [get_browser()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-browser.php)

```
<?php
$browser = get_browser(null, true);
print_r($browser);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is just looking to see if the user agent string contains "MSIE". You can do the same check for "Chrome", since that's going to be present in the chrome user agent string.

see: http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Chrome/

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Chrome') !== false &&    
(preg_match('/windows|win32/i', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])))
{
// Windows and Chrome 
}
```