# How to set cakephp to disable a line of code if a certain browser is not being used

Tags: cakephp, browser

I am planning to integrate JQUERY mobile into a web application, however when I add JQUERY mobile it does not work that well in IE, ence I need a plugin or a code to disable the javascript CDN code of JQUERY mobile if the browser is IE or a browser that does not support HTML5 functions. This will allow persons to view the application online without issues.

My default layout is in 'default.ctp'

Here is my header code:

```
<head>
<!--<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Tauri' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
<link href='http://jomhuriye.99k.org/fonts/discoveryfonts.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<?php echo $this->Html->charset(); ?>
<title>
    <?php echo $title_for_layout; ?>
</title>
<?php
    echo $this->Html->meta('icon');
?>
<?php
    echo $this->Html->css('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->css('default');
    echo $this->Html->css('flat-ui');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-1.7.1');
    echo $this->Html->script('jquery-ui');
    echo $this->Html->css('calendar');
    //echo $this->Html->script('sliding.form');
    echo $this->Html->script('bootstrap');
    echo $this->Html->script('application');
    echo $this->Html->script('datetime');
    echo $this->Html->script('calendar');
    echo $this->Html->script('forms');

    echo $this->fetch('meta');
    echo $this->fetch('css');
    echo $this->fetch('script');
?>
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-         1.3.1.min.js"></script>
             <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.1/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css" />
             <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
             </head>
```

I would like to set the last three lines to "disable" if IE is being used or if the browser does not support HTML5.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

See these pages

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512(v=vs.85).aspx
- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html

and use conditional comments.

Example from the second page:

```
<!--[if IE 6]>
Special instructions for IE 6 here
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: The thing is that since "IE >= 10 is now so advanced" (according to Microsoft) that there are no conditional comments for an IE version higher than 9.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep it simple with conditional comments, but as @Borislav Sabev  said, IE > 9 will not count there. Another approach is to do it with php.

We use a component, [Browscap](https://github.com/felixge/cakephp-browscap), to determine the browser in the controller side.

What you could do is add that component, and in the `beforeFilter` part of the `AppController` add a global variable to be passed to the view. Then in the view check for the variable value and if the conditions are correct, then echo the jquery mobile call.

Should be something like this

```
class AppController extends Controller {
    public  $components = array('Browscap' /*and the others*/);

    public function beforeFilter() {
         $this->Browscap->startup();
         $browser = $this->Browscap->get();
         $this->set('browser', $browser['browser']);
    }
}
```

and in the view

```
if ($browser == 'IE')
   //do nothing
else
   echo jquery thing
```

Of course, you don't need to use the component, you can write your [own function or use pure php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php) in the AppController to check for that. You can also do that in the view only and not involve the controller, but I wouldn't recommend that, it's cleaner to leave it in the controller. But I think that's a matter of taste...

Anyway, keep in mind that nothing is completely reliable, browsers lie.