# user browser detecting information in php

Tags: javascript, php, email, mysqli

I am trying for the long time to search the function that help to find the user browser name. I did my best but not any solution.

If there is not function so tell me How I can send this javascript value to email.

I try to send the a lot of time but it goes in this form userbrowser

while userbroswer should be chrome or something else. I try to use this on Local server without mail it's showing well but when it goes to mail it shows the script instead of information.

Code of js here:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
``<script type="text/javascript">
  $browsers = ["Firefox", "Chrome", "Safari", "Opera", 
                    "MSIE", "Trident", "Edge"];
    $userbrowser 
    $useragent = navigator.userAgent;
    for (var i = 0; i < browsers.length; i++) {
    if( useragent.indexOf(browsers[i]) > -1 ) {
        userbrowser = browsers[i];
        break;
    }
};

switch(userbrowser) {
    case 'MSIE':
        userbrowser = 'Internet Explorer';
        break;

    case 'Trident':
        userbrowser = 'Internet Explorer';
        break;

    case 'Edge':
        userbrowser = 'Internet Explorer';
        break;
     }
</script>
```

Comment: why not just do it in php, it would be lot easier to then email.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser)

Comment: IdontDownVote. If you have function Please send me

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php

Answer (score 0):

for browser Detection, we use `navigator.appName` and `navigator.appVersion` . `navigator.appName` detects the web browser and `navigator.appVersion` describes the browser version.

```js
var objappVersion = navigator.appVersion;
var objAgent = navigator.userAgent;
var objbrowserName  = navigator.appName;
var objfullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
var objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var objOffsetName,objOffsetVersion,ix;
console.log(objAgent);
console.log(objBrMajorVersion);

if ((objOffsetVersion=objAgent.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
  objbrowserName = "Chrome";
  objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion+7);
}

else if ((objOffsetVersion=objAgent.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
  objbrowserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
  objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion+5);
}


else if ((objOffsetVersion=objAgent.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
  objbrowserName = "Firefox";
}

else if ((objOffsetVersion=objAgent.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
  objbrowserName = "Safari";
  objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion+7);
  if ((objOffsetVersion=objAgent.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
    objfullVersion = objAgent.substring(objOffsetVersion+8);
}


if ((ix=objfullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
  objfullVersion=objfullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=objfullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
  objfullVersion=objfullVersion.substring(0,ix);

objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(''+objfullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(objBrMajorVersion)) {
  objfullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
  objBrMajorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}
document.write(''
               +'Browser name  = '+objbrowserName+'<br>'
               +'Full version  = '+objfullVersion+'<br>'
               +'Major version = '+objBrMajorVersion+'<br>'
               +'navigator.appName = '+navigator.appName+'<br>'
              )
```