# Is it possible to detect user's mobile info on php?

Tags: php, mobile, user-agent

I just working on a project and now I can using User-agent detect users OS and users browser (with version). but now my question is: It is possible to detect what is the brand (or better brand and model) of users mobile in a php website? (using php or javascript)
I already test http://mobiledetect.net/ project but it's not working good for me. I tested with my samsung galaxy a10 and that detects I using android and my browser is chrome but my device detected as a tablet on it.
Do you have any way to solve this? thank you all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reliable user browser detection with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2257597/reliable-user-browser-detection-with-php)

Comment: Why would you need to know?